# Tensorflow textsum model- different source and target vocabs

Tags: tensorflow

I want to use the textsum model for tagging named entities. Hence the target size vocab is very small.  While training there doesn't seem to be an option to provide different vocabs on the encoder and on the decoder side-or is there?
See [code lines](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/199db00e33a9c116c8d6a07f3724e56faac02a3e/textsum/seq2seq_attention.py#L193-L195) on Github

`if hps.mode == 'train':
    model = seq2seq_attention_model.Seq2SeqAttentionModel(hps, vocab, num_gpus=FLAGS.num_gpus)`

Answer (score 0):

Hrishikesh I don't believe there is a way to provide separate vocab files, but not fully understanding why you need it. The vocab simply provides a numerical way of representing a word.  Therefore when the model is working with these words, it uses the numerical representations of them.  Once the hypothesis is complete and the statistical choices for words have been chosen, it then simply uses the vocab file to convert back the vocab index to it's associated word. I hope this helps answer your question and solidify why you shouldn't need to have separate vocab files. That said, I may jsut be misunderstanding your need for it and I apologize if that is the case.

Comment: To clarify: I want to take something like : "This shirt is blue" and tag it as -> ["this", "shirt", "is", "blue"]-> ["no_color", "no_color", "no_color", "color"]`. Thus my target side vocab only has "color" and "noc_color". When the model does a softmax to predict a token on target side I want it to predict only one of "color" and "no_color"

Answer (score 0):

No there is no out-of-the-box option to use the textsum in this way. I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be possible to modify the architecture to achieve this, though. Would be interested if you pointed towards some literature on using seq2seq w/attention models for NER